# Loop or another instrument for range in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not programmer but trying to automate my routine job in **VBA** Excel.

I wrote "If else" code in VBA for my table for one row and it works. But in my table has 20 rows. And I need to work "If else" condition in every row. Variable has to change data, execute condition and go to another row and etc.

I imagine logic of code, suppose I need **LOOP** for range. But I don't understand syntax of Loop.

Below my code.

**Variables**: text, score1, score2, score3  - has to change cell in every row. After execution go to next row below him.

**If Else** condition has to work in every row (of range). After execution go to next row below him.

**Result** - after "past value" go to next row below him and past there another value of next **If Else** condition of new row.

Help me to solve this task, please.

```
Sub Test()

Dim score1 As Double, score2 As Double, score3 As Double, result As String, text As String

text = Range("G3").Value
score1 = Range("C3").Value
score2 = Range("D3").Value
score3 = Range("E3").Value

name1 = "Company A"       
name2 = "Company B"
currenc = "Dollars"


If score1 = 0 And score2 = 0 Then
    result = text + " " + name1 + " didn't count and " + name2 + " didn't count."

ElseIf score1 = score2 Then
    result = text + " " + name1 + " some code..............."

ElseIf score1 > score2 And score2 <> 0 Then
    result = text + " " + name1 + "  some code..............."

ElseIf score1 < score2 And score1 <> 0 Then
    result = text + " " + name1 + "  some code..............."

Else
    result = text + " 00000000"

End If

Range("I3").Value = result

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
Dim ifrom as long, ito as long
Dim i As Long

ifrom = 3
ito = Range("G3").End(xlDown).Row ' find the row above the 1st blank cell in column G

name1 = "Company A"       
name2 = "Company B"
currenc = "Dollars"

For i = ifrom to ito

    text = Range("G" & i).Value
    score1 = Range("C" & i).Value
    score2 = Range("D" & i).Value
    score3 = Range("E" & i).Value

    If score1 = 0 And score2 = 0 Then
        result = text + " " + name1 + " didn't count and " + name2 + " didn't count."
    ElseIf score1 = score2 Then
        result = text + " " + name1 + " some code..............."
    ElseIf score1 > score2 And score2 <> 0 Then
        result = text + " " + name1 + "  some code..............."
    ElseIf score1 < score2 And score1 <> 0 Then
        result = text + " " + name1 + "  some code..............."
    Else
        result = text + " 00000000"
    End If

    Range("I" & i).Value = result
Next i
```

Comment: Wonderful! It works. Thank you. Will be perfect if you add comments, want to understand logic.